# How can I get real-time database table's notifications in .Net Core 2.2 , SignalR & MySQL?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr

I building a small webpage where I'm listing set of data which stored in a MySQL database. I need to show data in real-time.

Whenever a new record adds to a particular table, it should show in the webpage.

- .NET Core 2.2
- MySQL (latest)

Appreciate if anyone can give thoughts/references on how to achieve this.

Comment: How will you insert a new record, by EF Core or manually modifing the database? If previous, you could try refer [How should I listen for entities being added/deleted/modified in ef core? #5970](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/5970). If later, it is impossible currently.

Comment: @TaoZhou records will insert from another application, not the .net core application.

Comment: did you try 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-tracing-mysql-custom-listeners.html